# How to align textInput with checkbox

Tags: r, shiny, checklistbox

I am making an analysis tool in Rshiny. I want to be able to select the groups to display in a reactive plot and allow for custom colors to be chosen.

This is what I have for the UI right now:

[image: Current Predicament]

I would like for it to be more obvious that each box is related to the items in the checklist instead of hovering to the side. Optimally, I would want the textbox to be flush next to its respective checklist item and for everything to be aligned. Closer to what I've mocked up below:
[image: mockup of desired layout]

This is the code snippet that makes it (colors don't match because the actual code has a function that makes the colors):

```
ncolors = c("red","blue","green","black")
groupColorsTextInput = list()
for (i in 1:4) {
  groupColorsTextInput = list(groupColorsTextInput, # you must use list to concatenate
                           textInput(inputId = paste0("group", i, "Color"),
                                     label = NULL,
                                     value = ncolors[i]))
}
fluidRow(column(5, checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "groups", # which groups in each plot
                         label = "Include Groups:",
                         choices = NA,
                         selected = NA)),
               column(5, groupColorsTextInput))
```

I realize I could just put a label to the side of the textInput's, but there should be a way to do what I'm trying to do, right? Would I need to make 4 different checkboxes and put each checkbox and textInput into its own fluidrow? Thanks.

Comment: Are the checkbox items related to selectInputs ? e.g. 1_1 in first selection shud appear on left of inputBox containing HexCode?  Can you show what you want?  if the two are not related why would you place them side by side.?

Comment: @anuanand I've included a mockup. I would like for it to be more obvious that each box is related to the items in the checklist, where each item in the checklist is represented by the color in the adjacent textInput in the plots elsewhere in the app

Comment: Sorry . Tried last night some time but its too difficult in shiny with its own components.  We spend more time in UI than server. Try CSS + JS combo. I don't have time to test today so don't want to keep you waiting. Sorry again.

Comment: If possible, please post the reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(shiny)

ncolors = c("red","blue","green","black")

checkInput <- function(index) {
    fluidRow(
        div(
            style = "
                width: 30px; bottom: 0; height: 34px; padding-right: 50px; display: inline-block;
            ", 
            checkboxGroupInput(
                inputId = paste0("groups", index), # which groups in each plot
                label = NULL,
                choices = NA,
                selected = NA
            )
        ),
        div(
            style = "
                display: inline-block;
            ", 
            textInput(
                inputId = paste0("group", index, "Color"),
                label = NULL,
                value = ncolors[index])
        )
    )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$b("Include Groups:"), br(),
    lapply(1:4, checkInput)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Increase the value of `padding-right: 50px` if your text on left is long.

[image]